# I get this error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to code a nav sidebar that when someone clicks on an li the .sidebar-nav__ul__li-child div opens.

But instead I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

This is the HTML:

```
<nav class="sidebar-nav">
<ul class="sidebar-nav__ul">
    <li class="sidebar-nav__ul__li">
    <a href="#">Home</a>
        <div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child">

        </div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child ends-->
    </li><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li ends-->

    <li class="sidebar-nav__ul__li">
    <a href="#">About</a><div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-arrow"></div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-arrow ends-->
        <div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel">
                <li class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li">
                <a href="#"> About us child</a><div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-arrow"></div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-arrow ends-->
                    <div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child">
                        <ul class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel">
                            <li class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel-li">
                            <a href="#">About us child child</a>
                            </li><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel-li ends-->
                        </ul><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel ends-->
                    </div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child ends-->
                </li><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li ends-->
            </ul><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel ends-->
        </div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child ends-->
    </li><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li ends-->

    <li class="sidebar-nav__ul__li">
    <a href="#">Contact</a><div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-arrow"></div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-arrow ends-->
        <div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel">
                <li class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li">
                <a href="#">Contact us child</a><div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-arrow"></div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-arrow ends-->
                    <div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child">
                        <ul class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel">
                            <li class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel-li">
                            <a href="#">Contact us child child</a>
                            </li><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel-li ends-->
                        </ul><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel ends-->
                    </div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child ends-->
                </li><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li ends-->
            </ul><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel ends-->
        </div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child ends-->
    </li><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li ends-->


    <li class="sidebar-nav__ul__li">
    <a href="#">Contact</a><div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-arrow"></div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-arrow ends-->
        <div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel">
                <li class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li">
                <a href="#">Contact us child</a><div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-arrow"></div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-arrow ends-->
                    <div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child">
                        <ul class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel">
                            <li class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel-li">
                            <a href="#">Contact us child child</a>
                            </li><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel-li ends-->
                        </ul><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel ends-->
                    </div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child ends-->
                </li><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li ends-->
            </ul><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel ends-->
        </div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child ends-->
    </li><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li ends-->


    <li class="sidebar-nav__ul__li">
    <a href="#">Contact</a><div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-arrow"></div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-arrow ends-->
        <div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel">
                <li class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li">
                <a href="#">Contact us child</a><div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-arrow"></div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-arrow ends-->
                    <div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child">
                        <ul class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel">
                            <li class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel-li">
                            <a href="#">Contact us child child</a>
                            </li><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel-li ends-->
                        </ul><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel ends-->
                    </div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child ends-->
                </li><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li ends-->
            </ul><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel ends-->
        </div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child ends-->
    </li><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li ends-->


    <li class="sidebar-nav__ul__li">
    <a href="#">Contact</a><div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-arrow"></div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-arrow ends-->
        <div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel">
                <li class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li">
                <a href="#">Contact us child</a><div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-arrow"></div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-arrow ends-->
                    <div class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child">
                        <ul class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel">
                            <li class="sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel-li">
                            <a href="#">Contact us child child</a>
                            </li><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel-li ends-->
                        </ul><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child-thirdLevel ends-->
                    </div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li-child ends-->
                </li><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel-li ends-->
            </ul><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child-secondLevel ends-->
        </div><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li-child ends-->
    </li><!--sidebar-nav__ul__li ends-->
</ul><!--sidebar-nav__ul ends-->
```

This is the JavaScript:

```
    <script>
       const sidebarLis = document.querySelectorAll('.sidebar-nav__ul__li');

       sidebarLis.forEach(function(sideBarLi) {
           const openArrow =  sideBarLi.querySelector('.sidebar-nav__ul__li-arrow');
           const firstLiChild = sideBarLi.querySelector('.sidebar-nav__ul__li-child');

           openArrow.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
               firstLiChild.classList.add('sidebar-nav-show');
           });

       });
   </script>
```

Can someone please help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: When does your script run?

Comment: I added it right after the above html.